# why do I get SQL syntax error? Is it to do with the JOptionPane?

Tags: java, sql, swing, joptionpane

I have used the same method below for other swing component's actionlisteners and has worked fine, as soon as I use it for JoptionPane it appears to go wrong! (Strings one, two, three, and four are textfields in my JOptionPane and object message2 includes them)

```
insertButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Object initialSelectionValue = null;
            Statement statement = null;

            if (SisSelected == true) {
                String insert = "INSERT INTO `S` VALUES ('" + one + "','"
                        + two + "','" + three + "','" + four + "');";
                JOptionPane
                        .showInputDialog(message2, initialSelectionValue);

                one.getText();
                two.getText();
                three.getText();
                four.getText();

                try {
                    statement = ResultSetTableModelFactory.connection
                            .createStatement();
                    statement.executeUpdate(insert);
                } catch (SQLException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

                displayQueryResults("select * from S;");

            }
```

Comment: Did it occur to you to escape the content of the textboxes

Comment: What's the error you got ? Can you show us ?

Comment: Or use prepared statements?

Comment: You've already set the values one, two and three to the insert statement, then you "appear" to be asking for them  which is to late. Using one/two/three.getText does nothing. Infact, your insert statement will contain the results of toString for the one, two, three text fields, not their text. initialSelectionValue is also null, so not sure what that's suppose to be doing...

Comment: @GabrielL. Hi, this is the error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$UpdateHandler,alignm' at line 1

Comment: It seems one is empty, two, three and four are 0. You should debug to see what's in one, two, three and four.